# Trying to change the total field calculation in gravity forms wordpress

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

Am trying to change the total field value in gravity forms. The total field should be divided by 1000. i have the total value as $total = $total/1000  in common.php in gravity but I donot see any change in the forms how can do custom total calculation in gravity forms

Comment: What have you done? Please show some code.